# Matrix --> ijv (or triplet or co-ordinate) format --> file in Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have  a huge matrix and wish to save it in triplet format (row-value-column) format in a file, how do I achieve this in numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use something like this:

```
I, J = np.indices(values.shape)
triplets = np.column_stack(ar.ravel() for ar in (I, J, values))
np.savetxt(filename, triplets, '%i %i %.9f')
```

Comment: The problem is that the indices are written with one decimal place (they are integers) and there is no new line between consecutive rows in triplet format.

Comment: @dineshdileep: You're right. I edited the last line in the code, hopefully it gives the desired format. I do believe that `numpy.savetxt` uses a Python loop so it might be relatively slow.

Comment: It works fine for me!. I made the format as '%i\t%i\t%.9f\n' which is what I want. However, it leaves a newline at the eof which is sort of ok. Do you mind explaining what is happening in your code, how it works?